# Code injection - Solaris & Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, solaris, elf

I have an executable module created by third party. I would like to "inject" my code (kind of watchdog running in separate thread) into this process.

So far there are two possible ways - one is to run my code as executable and dynamically load a proess on top of it (seems to be very hard and tricky) or to make my code a shared object, load it via LD_PRELOAD and initialize from some static variable constructor.

Are there more convenient ways to do this ?
My OS are Linux x86 and Solaris-SPARC.

Update: If possible, I'd like not to patch the process, but load my code dynamicaly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [InjectSo](http://www.securiteam.com/tools/5EP0P157PG.html). There's a [Powerpoint presentation](http://www.blackhat.com/presentations/bh-europe-01/shaun-clowes/bh-europe-01-clowes.ppt) that explains how it works. I haven't gotten around to trying it out yet.

Comment: Dmitry, on what specific system were you able to get it to work? I haven't been able to yet, with a wide array of old and new systems.

Answer (score 2):

[Hotpatch](https://github.com/vikasnkumar/hotpatch) should do this for you. It is more capable than injectso.

Answer (score 0):

Rob Kennedy told you about InjectSo - that's probably what you need.

Beware that the introduction of a thread into a non-threaded process would be fraught with synchronization issues.  The problems are less serious if the application is already threaded, but even so, the application may object to a thread that it doesn't know about.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the mentioned InjectSo but it is a noteworthy information.
If you are looking for alternatives here is a simple way to inject your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
int main()
{
    struct passwd* pswd = getpwuid(1000);
    if(pswd) 
        printf("%s\n", pswd->pw_name);
    return 0;
}
```

`gcc test.c -o test`

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static char* hocus = "hocus pocus";

struct passwd *getpwuid(uid_t uid)
{
    static struct passwd *(*orig_getpwuid)(uid_t uid);
    if(!orig_getpwuid) {
        orig_getpwuid = (struct passwd* (*)(uid_t))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "getpwuid");
    }

    struct passwd* original_passwd = (*orig_getpwuid)(uid);
    if(original_passwd) {
        original_passwd->pw_name = hocus;
    }
    // your code here
    return original_passwd;
}
```

`gcc inject.c -shared -o libinject.so`

run with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. LD_PRELOAD=libinject.so ./test`

Should say `hocus pocus`. You can override arbitrary `libc` functions, like `printf`, `snprintf` - just find what is that module using.

In the "your code here" you can start arbitrary threads, watchdogs etc.